# Target first child of parent

Tags: jquery

My html code looks like this:

```
...more rows
<tr class="highlightRow" id="tr0" style="display: table-row;">
    <td>0.  TIC&nbsp;</td>
    <td>123456&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" value="12345" id="txt0" name="txtTicRequired0" class="tic">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" onclick="checkIfChecked(0);" checked="" id="ck0">
    </td>
</tr>
...more rows
```

My starting point is the id of the input field at the 3rd `td` element and I want to target the first `td` of the `tr`.

To go to the `tr` I use: `$('#txt0').parent().parent();` But how can I go from that parent to the first `td` element using the [first-clild](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) selector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
$('#txt0').closest('tr').find('td:first');
```

Comment: Very nice. I've never liked chaining `parent()` calls since it feels brittle to me - too tied to the structure of the document.

Comment: Agreed. Plus it's really what closest() was meant to handle.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of chaining `parent()` calls, use `closest()` with a selector:

```
var $firstTd = $('#txt0').closest('tr').find('td:first');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) selector to achieve this

Try this

```
$('#txt0').closest('tr').find('td:first');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like

```
$('#txt0').parent().parent().find('td:eq(0)');
```

Or try with `first` instead of `eq` like

```
$('#txt0').parent().parent().find('td:first');
```

Comment: I tried the first solution provided like this: ` 

$('#'+inputId).parent().parent().('td:eq(0)').css('font-weight','bold');` but my console complaints about `SyntaxError: missing name after . operator`

Comment: Have you seeen my edit..??Please see it.I have changed with `find` immidiatly that I forgotted while typing